# difference between rational and fraction

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, number-systems

my question is are we doing the same thing in $\frac{6}{-7}$ and $\frac{-6}{7}$? my argument is they are giving the same answer but at first we are dividing by $-7$ and second by $7$, so we are actually making changes to get the same answer, am I right? now fractions if only can have the denominator from the whole number set, then all fractions are rational but the converse is not true? again we can see the members in the set of rational and fractions are the same, but if the converse is not true can we say that both sets are the same? please help me to solve these 3 doubts

Comment: Don't confuse the number with the ways to represent it. $- \frac{6}{7}$, $\frac{-6}{7}$, $\frac{6}{-7}$, $-1+\frac{1}{7}$ and the smallest root of $7x^2-x-6$ are all the same number (which is a rational number) even though you can represent or refer to it in different ways.

Comment: Every rational number can be written as a fraction of two integers , in fact it is the definition of "rational number" that such a representation exists. So, if "fraction" is meant as a fraction of integers the set of fractions is identical to the set of rational numbers. The representation is however not unique.